# How can we import data from CSV file uploaded on Sharpoint to the CRM entities using Azure Logic App?

Tags: azure, sharepoint, dynamics-crm, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

Following is the exact scenario:

There is a SharePoint site where the users upload CSV and XML files. We are planning to create an Azure Logic App that should pick the CSV files and import them into CRM to create records for a specific entity. If there is an XML file, then it should be converted to the CSV file before the import starts.

I am aware that this can be done using a Windows Service, or even a console application. But we are more interested in making this happen through Azure Logic App as the scenario seems fitting well in the Logic App's model. But not getting much help online or documentation, and due to which unable to figure out how exactly it can be achieved.

I have created a Logic App in Azure, and also a trigger which gets invoked when a new file is created on a SharePoint site. Can anyone guide me what should be the next steps?

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can orchestrate this using logic apps, but any parsing/processing of the CSV file would be best achieved using using an Azure Function. Logic Apps provide native integration with Azure Functions, so you can easily prepare the input and consume the output of your function.

[image: Logic Apps integration with Azure Functions]